# Selenium Test inadvertantly triggers hover menu

Tags: java, selenium

I have a selenium based  (v2.32 jar) test using java and have just noticed a really odd issue, in that i click a 'sign in' button at the top of the page, after which i then need to click a 'new user' button which is now shown in the page centre.

However, the nav menu drop down is getting triggered as its in the direct path between where my current cursor is and button i want to click and once the hover menu gets triggered, it sits above the new button, making it unclickable.

Is there a way to tell Selenium to ignore the hover menu in instances such as this ?

This is the method i am using

```
public void clickWhenReady(By locator, int timeout) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
    log.fine("Waiting to click element: " + locator);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
            .elementToBeClickable(locator));
    log.fine("Clicking element: " + locator);
    element.click();
}
```

Comment: Actually - i've sort of got a workaround, which is to move to an element in the footer first, which ensures i always move way past the nav elements. Interested to hear of anyone else who has encountered this though.

Comment: Steve,which browser are you using?I have faced a similar problem with firefox which I solved by checking the compatibility between the browser and the selenium jars and then updating the selenium jars to suit the browser.

Comment: Hi Madusudanan,

Were using selenium jar 2.32 and fireforx browser version 19.0
We could upgrade the browser, although i did notice a previous issue with upgrading ,which i guess wasn't solved quickly enough.

Which jar version and browser version are you using ?

Comment: I am using the latest available versions of both.Are you sure that the issue is not with the application itself.Can you post a part of the HTML source here.Also try selecting the element by direct javascript itself, like document.findelementbyid.click or something like that.